# How to get a processing script to run in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, processing.js

I am making a program that requires a string to be turned into a processing.js script. Currently, the code below makes a `<script type="text/processing" data-processing-target="canvas">` tag and adds a string in it but how do I get it to run?

```
 function runProcessing() {
            var input = "<script type=\"text/processing\" data-processing-target=\"canvas\">";
            input += document.getElementById("userInput").value;
            document.getElementById('processingCode').innerHTML = input;
            console.log(document.getElementById('processingCode').innerHTML);
        }
```

In outher words, How do I turn this...

```
void setup() {}
```

Into this...

```
<script type="text/processing" data-processing-target="canvas">
void setup() {}
</script>
```

And run it.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking. Processing needs a `canvas` to work. You can put that `canvas` inside a `div` if you want to. Can you please post a [mcve]? Can you please be more specific about exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: which libary you're using for your process script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just need to create a new Processing instance, passing in the target canvas and the sketch source. You do not need to actually add in the html into the dom

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('yourCanvasID');
var source = document.getElementById("userInput").value;

var instance = new Processing(canvas, source);
```

But if you do wish to add it in as html, you should be able to call `Processing.reload()` after adding in the html to reinitialize the sketches